# How to detect an (inadvertent) write-only property in my beans?

Tags: java, javabeans

I have been working on my first Java project with the 'Drools Planner' package, using the JavaBean pattern for my classes. I inadvertently coded one of my classes to have a **write-only property**, which triggered [this bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3247)

> might indeed return null if the property is write-only, as explained
>   in the JavaBeans(TM) Specification 1.01 Final Release

---

How do I programatically check my classes and see which one has the offending write-only property?

Or, since it's a matter of just 6 classes, is there some rule of thumb to find it by eyeball?

Comment: Isn't this what tests are for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programatically you can use the bean descriptor to figure out the classes with no getter for properties

```
import java.beans.*

Class[] clazzes=new Class[]{<your classes here>};
for(Class c:clazzes){
   try {
    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(c).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        System.out.println(pd.getName()+":"+pd.getDisplayName());
          if (pd.getReadMethod() == null){
          System.out.println("No read method for : "+pd.getName()+" in : "+c);
       }
     }
} catch (IntrospectionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

You can also check the IDE's code completion to check whether your all properties have getters, initiate it and then type in 'get'and 'is' it will list all the getters :)

Comment: uh, I did `Class[] clazzes=new Class[]{Digit};` and compiler gave `helloworld.java:71: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Digit`, what did I do wrong here?

Comment: give Digit.class like Class[] clazzes=new Class[]{Digit.class};

Comment: There is a compile error `helloworld.java:74: unreported exception java.beans.IntrospectionException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
 for (PropertyDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(c).getPropertyDescriptors()) {`